# How do I localize ReportViewer labels, column headers, etc.?

Tags: c#, localization, reportviewer

I need to localize labels / column header for a ReportViewer report.  From what I've read, there are two ways you can do this:

1)  Create a RDLC file for each language or

2)  Create one RDLC file and parse this at runtime, replacing the label/header values with the strings for the current culture.

I'm thinking #2 is gonna be less work in the long run, but I would like to confirm that the newest version doesn't support localization out of the box.  Am I correct that I'll have to roll my own?  Actually, I'll probably use the solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/269dde8b-0b84-4455-867d-5f09d248b5c6/).

Comment: Probably this could help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/27499952/4365427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of localisation available in the 2010 (2008?) version but another quick option is included below:

An option I have used is to create a language dataset then pass in values from language files. So when you want to use a text string you end up with just references to dataset values, normally we used a long dataset with only 1 row and then used the first() function.

We stored XML files for languages and then just populated a dataset on the local report. Not too sure if that would work on remote mode reports though.

Comment: Ya, I came to a similar conclusion.  I created a business object with property wrappers for the localized strings in resx files.

Comment: I ran into a road-block.  Can't seem to figure out how to pass in localized table header strings into a reportviewer table.  The table auto-fills in the header by parsing the property name.  But, I would like to customize this with a translated value.  And, I can't seem to put a textbox in the header part of a table.