# Multi-language report in C#

Tags: c#, localization, reporting

I'm writing reporting application in C# (local reports). I've made report patterns (rdlc files) and now I'm trying to make them autotranslating due to localization of user. I've managed to make a single translation (translation of one field, but there are many of them) with resource file, but this requires parameter to every textbox I use in report :

```
ReportParameter p = new ReportParameter("Report1Parameter3", GlobalStrings.FieldText);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(p);
```

Is there any way to make it more "direct" than using additional parameter for every text field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should put all field to your dataset, and process translate before bind data for every user.

Comment: What you suggest is to create database with stored translations and give up on .resx files, or include them (resx files) as datasets?

Comment: I think for your purpose, give up on .resx files and use a table to store all need-to-translate fields, then processing translate before pass it to a dataset and assign this dataset to reportviewer.

Answer (score 1):

This has been the solution in my desktop application.
Let's say you have a separate resource file stored in the same folder of your application and named **Resources.dll** created with a resx file named **Reports.resx** with **Public** access

#### Step 1

Set permissions for local report (this should be repeated after every reset)

```
<YourReportViewer>.LocalReport.SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain(new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted))
```

#### Step 2

In your rdlc report add following code (under report properties or manually edit rdlc file adding the code under **<Report>/<Code>** tag)

```
Private Shared Resources As Type = Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Resources.dll")).GetType("Resources.Reports")

Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(name As String) As String
    Get
        Return Resources.GetProperty(name, Reflection.BindingFlags.Static Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(Nothing).ToString()
    End Get
End Property
```

#### Step 3

In your report you can reference strings in resources using an expression like this:

```
=Code!<NameOfYourResource>
```